# WP_Mail $to field works when hardcoded but not when using ACF field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to send an email using WP_Mail and I would like the `to` field to be populated with an ACF option. I am doing that like this within my `functions.php` file:

```
$to = get_field('admin_email', 'option');
wp_mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

I have confirmed that this is getting the correct email by echoing out `$to`. But the e-mail never gets received. However, if I hardcode the email:

```
$to = 'admin@example.com';
```

The e-mail is sent successfully. Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: What is coming up if you var_dump $to?

Comment: @HowardE it says `string(17) "admin@example.com"`

Comment: Do you want the answer?